# laravel 5 console команды имеет не верный путь после переноса root папки

Tags: php, laravel

После переноса папки с Laravel 5 на другой диск, команды (вроде миграции) по прежнему ссылаются на старый путь.
Было

> D:\MyTest2\

Стало

> C:\Server\localhost\

После ввода любой консольной команды, даже artisan config:cache в логах консоли пишется старый путь

> Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in D:\MyTest2...

PS: не могу пока ничего нового создать через консоль, т.к. ссылки идут по старому пути.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работал через PHPShtorm и, чтобы исправить команды после переноса, нужно было в 2-х файлах изменить полные пути в папке .ide:

1. workspace.xml

   `<component name="RecentsManager">
   <key name="MoveFile.RECENT_KEYS">
     <recent name="C:\Server\localhost\resources\assets" />
     <recent name="C:\Server\localhost\public\storage\img" />
   </key>
   </component>`
2. Tool_based_on_Symfony_Console_07_05_17_12_20_artisan.xml

   `<framework xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/frameworkDescriptionVersion1.1.4.xsd" frameworkId="com.symfony.component" name="Tool_based_on_Symfony_Console_07.05.17 12:20_artisan" invoke="C:\php\php.exe c:\Server\localhost\artisan" alias="artisan" enabled="true" version="2">`